# Как заменить точку на запятую в input type="number"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Как можно заменить точку на запятую в `input type="number"`, при этом сохранить ввод отрицательных чисел и диапазон, установленный в `HTML`?

```js
function doubleValidate(input) {
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[.]/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="@item.TempAirBrest" name="TempAirBrest"  min="-99.0" max="99.0" step="0.1" required onkeypress="doubleValidate(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Во-первых, событие onkeypress происходит до изменения значения поля.
- Во-вторых, input.value для инпута с типом number возвращает знчение с точкой (даже если в поле отображается запятая).
- В-третьих, input.value ожидает разделитель точку и отбросит строку после запятой.

Но раз вы всё равно делаете проверку, почему бы не добавить в неё и min/max ограниения заменив type на `text`? (Хотя возможно на телефонах тип number откроет цифровую клавиатуру, надо проверить)

Или меняйте разделитель не при вводе, а потом.

Обратите внимание, что с текстовыми полями не всё так просто. В них можно вставлять скопированное, автозаполнять плагинами и всякое такое.
Событие `onkeypress` может и не произойти. Я обычно на фокус вешаю интервал с валидатором и убиваю его на блюр.

Comment: я пробовал через событие onkeyup и onkeydown результат тот же. Дело в том, что я эти данные посылаю через запрос и принимаю их как тип double для последующего сохранения в БД (MS SQL там double через запятую). Возможно, мне необходимо принимать эти данные как string и уже на сервере производить приведение, но опять же, придется парсить полученные данные, выискивая точку, заменить ее на запятую, после чего только пытаться преобразовать string в double. Мне казалось, что проще на стороне клиента проверить валидность введенных данных и принимать значения типа double в самом запросе.

Comment: `input.value` возвращает то, что я в него введу. Я принимал его типом `double` на `с# (asp.net mvc)` в виде `public IActionResult Save(List<double>TempAirBrest)`. В случае отправки, с запятой проблем нету, я получаю все прекрасно, но если стоит точка, естественно данные не приходят в переменную, т.к не являются `double` (необходима запятая).

Comment: @Дмитрий вы же понимаете, что приведение типов и валидация на сервере понадобятся в любом случае (нет никакой проблемы отправить на сервер **любую** строку, обойдя ограничения инпута). Насчёт `input.value` -- просто выведите его (например `console.log(input.value)`) и посмотрите, что в нём.

Comment: Да, действительно, вы правы насчет `input.value` . Также соглашусь с вами по поводу необходимой валидации на сервере, думаю в таком случае не актуально, что будет отправляться из `input`. Ваш ответ косвенно решил мою проблема. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример работает если функцию записать так:

```
fun = function(input) {
   input.value = input.value.replace(/[.]/g, ",");
}
```

И, соответственно, **onKeyPress="fun(this)"** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztNHL/66/)

Comment: В вашем примере вы используете input(type="text"), а я хочу что бы скрипт работал в input(type="number"), т.к хочу применить валидацию HTML5.

Comment: @Дмитрий да, извините, не совсем точно воспроизвел ваш пример. Но за то, в качестве оправдания нашел вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178332/force-decimal-point-instead-of-comma-in-html5-number-input-client-side

Comment: @Дмитрий вот пример немного другого подхода - замена запятых не во время ввода, а после нажатия на кнопку отпавки формы. Может быть вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407109/new-webkits-convert-decimal-comma-to-dot-and-vice-versa-in-number-type-inputs/24423879#24423879

Comment: благодарю за ссылки, они не решили моей проблемы но дали кое-какие идеи для решения. Скорее всего придется делать костыли и принимать значения в виде строк и обрабатывать их на стороне сервера.